# flex: creating a shortcut to another file/folder

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, filesystems, hyperlink, shortcut

Does anyone know of a method or strategy through which a shortcut can be created through Flex for the various platforms?  I've been examining the various flash.filesystem.File methods but did not notice anything that seemed noteworthy.

Thanks for the time and attention.

Comment: Are you referring to adding a shortcut for your application in an AIR installer, or rather using AIR after the installer to add extra short-cuts in an OS specific manner?

Comment: @shaunhusain I am referring to using the AIR app to add shortcuts in an OS specific manner.

Comment: okay I don't have a solution but I'll try searching around a bit and see if there's possibly a way using java, are you concerned with mobile as well or strictly desktop?  I'm just asking for clarification in case it helps get an answer out of someone else or in case I find some work around

Comment: @shaunhusain My focus is on desktop usage - Windows and Mac OS (and Linux if it's easily feasible).  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You won't be able to do it with Flex.
2. If you target AIR, there is this [XXMKLINK](http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy38.htm) program that allows you to create shortcuts from the command line. You can use the native process feature of AIR to leverage it.